# Xcode runs my iPhone 6 app as iPhone 4 size on iPad device

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator, xcode6.3, ios8.3

My app is built for iOS 8.3 and runs on different screen sizes. I laid everything out to fit iPhone 6 correctly.

When running  my app on iPad device the app is in letterbox iPhone 4 size screen, How can I get it to be iPhone 6 size inside the iPad ?